# Check for meta data before it is published

Tags: custom-field

I am using a church theme and custom post with its own set of meta data.

What i want to do isif a sermon post is published, WP will check whether someone included a video URL. If they do, check the 'Video Sermon' category. If they do not, do nothing.

My problem is that this code only works when the person click on Save the second times. I suspect it is because my code is checking data from the database. Since the first time someone posted, the data is not in the DB yet, 'Video Sermon' category is not checked.

Can someone showed me how to test the meta data before it is published or written in the DB?

Here's my code:

```
//Sermon post include Sermons category function add_sermons_automatically($post_ID) {
//check video

$video_info = get_post_meta('imic_vimeo_video', $post_ID);
 $video_info .= get_post_meta('imic_mp4_video', $post_ID);
 $video_info .= get_post_meta('imic_webm_video', $post_ID);
 $video_info .= get_post_meta('imic_ogg_video', $post_ID);
 $video_info .= get_post_meta('imic_youtube_video', $post_ID);

if (!empty($video_info)) {
    $sermons_cat = array(28);
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $sermons_cat, 'sermon-category');
}
} add_action('publish_sermon', 'add_sermons_automatically');
```

Thanks, Cliff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the `$_POST` fields as well - or better, instead of - for the same data which is being submitted, find this by the `name` attribute of the field input - it will *probably* match the existing keys you have. eg.

```
function add_sermons_automatically($post_ID) {
    if ( ( (isset($_POST['imic_vimeo_video'])) && ($_POST['imic_vimeo_video'] != '') ) 
      || ( (isset($_POST['imic_mp4_video'])) && ($_POST['imic_mp4_video'] != '') ) 
      || ( (isset($_POST['imic_ogg_video'])) && ($_POST['imic_ogg_video'] != '') ) 
      || ( (isset($_POST['imic_webm_video'])) && ($_POST['imic_webm_video'] != '') 
      || ( (isset($_POST['imic_youtube_video'])) && ($_POST['imic_youtube_video'] != '') ) ) {
        // (see alternative below)
        $sermons_cat = array(28);
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $sermons_cat, 'sermon-category');
    } else {
      // optionally remove the cateogory (see alternative below)
      // wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, '', 'sermon-category');
    }
}
```

If you check it this way instead of checking the database, you could also remove the category automatically if all video values have been removed.

Note that this will overwrite any other categories checked doing it this way, if you want to assign multiple categories you will need to do `wp_get_object_terms` first and add the category to that array before (re)setting it. eg.

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_ID, 'sermon-category');
$catids = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {$catids[] = $term->term_id;}
$catids[] = '28'; // vido sermon category
wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $catids, 'sermon-category');
```

Removing the video category automatically while preserving other categories is similar:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_ID, 'sermon-category');
$catids = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if ($term_id != 28) {$catids[] = $term->term_id;}
}
wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $catids, 'sermon-category');
```

And finally, you should do this on both publish and update (save)...

```
add_action('publish_sermon', 'add_sermons_automatically');
add_action('save_sermon', 'add_sermons_automatically');
```

Comment: Thanks for the introducing to me the $_POST and isset function.  This works great.